# How do I catch a mongoose ValidationError in an Express endpoint?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, error-handling

I am trying to create a post request to a MongoDB database. The schema has some required attributes and I am trying to handle ValidationErrors from requests that are missing these required attributes.

```
const post_property = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const ppty = new Properties(req.body);

        ppty.save();
        res.status(201).json({status: true, msg: "Property created", property: ppty});
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof mongoose.Error.ValidationError) {
            res.status(400).json({status: false, msg: error.message});
        }

        res.status(500).json({status: false, msg: error.message});
    }
}
```

My schema looks like this:

```
const PropertiesSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        address: {
            street: { type: String, required: true },
            number_or_apt: { type: String, required: true },
            city: { type: String, required: true },
            state_province: { type: String, required: true },
            zip_code: { type: String, required: true },
            country: { type: String, required: true },
            latitude: { type: String, required: true },
            longitude: { type: String, required: true },
        },
        property_images: [ String ],
    }
);

const Properties = mongoose.model('properties', PropertiesSchema);
```

Whenever I send the request with a missing required component the node server crashes. How can I handle this error?

I have tried implementing middleware to handle the error but that did not work.

Comment: you can use [express-async-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler).

Comment: can you show your shcema?

Comment: @TobokSitanggang Edited to add schema

Answer (score 0):

when defining a schema, you can also define error message for better approach

the schema would be like:

```
name: { type: String, required: [true, 'Name is required.'],  },
```

when create is called without `name` or any field that is `required`, it will thrown property err message inside propertiy `errors`:

```
`"Event validation failed: name: Name is required."`
```

regarding to [validation-errors documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#validation-errors), to handle the error would be:

````
try {
  ...
} catch (error) {
  const errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.errors.message
  //  use statuscode 400, because the error is about bad request.
  res.status(400).json({ status: false, msg: errMsg });
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using Promises as follows.

```
Properties.create(req.body)
  .then((ppty) => {
    ppty.save();
    res.status(201).json({status: true, msg: "Property created", property: ppty});
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.status(400).json({ status: false, msg: err });
});
```

This catches the validation errors correctly.